# LoginManager.getInstance.registerCallback() without facebook login button not called

Tags: android, facebook-login

This is my Library (.aar) project code

```
public static void fbLoginInitialize(Context context) {


    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(context);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    Log.i("in fb login chk1-->","in");

    LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)context, Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email","user_photos"));

fbLoginCheck(context);
    }

public static void fbLoginCheck(Context context){

    Log.i("in fb login chk2-->","in");

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {

                    Log.i("in fb login chk4-->","in");
                    Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                    if (profile != null) {
                        str_fb_user_id=profile.getId();
                        String f_name=profile.getFirstName();

                        Log.i("str_user_id",str_fb_user_id);

                    }
                    System.out.println("Success");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Log.i("in fb login chk5-->","in");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"You cancelled Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Log.i("in fb login chk6-->","in");
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,"Something went wrong",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.i("in fb login chk7-->","in");
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Login successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else if(resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED){
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"You cancelled Login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Below is my new project's activity code where i call my library project's method

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.btnFbLogin:

            LibraryMainActivity.fbLoginInitialize(MainActivity.this);

            break;
    }
}
```

When i run the new project, it pops up facebook login dialog on button click, i enter email, password and it gives me authorization dialog, when i click ok on that, it returns to my app but does not give me profile detail. None from `onSuccess()`,`onError()` or onCancel is called. Only `Log.i("in fb login chk1-->","in"); and Log.i("in fb login chk2-->","in");` prints. No logs further get printed. When i come out of my app and checks in facebook app, login has been done. Any help would be appreciated to help me tracing issue what is happening with registerCallback.. Thanks in Advance.